# Different result in debug with class Calendar

Tags: java

```
private java.sql.Date getHorizonEnd(Date date) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    return new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

If I pass the date 27 april 2020, I expected  01 august 2020, It work fine in debug if I have a breakpoint in this function, but otherwise I got 01 July 2020 ....

Comment: Seriously, don't use `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` anymore, they are outdated for good reasons... Can you briefly describe what you are trying to do? Adding 3 months to a date (and time) value?

Comment: This likely has to do with the debugger triggering an update fields which recalculates an intermediate state, while without debugging it skips those stages and only performs the recalculation once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks unnecessary but it work for me :

```
private java.sql.Date getHorizonEnd(Date date) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    cal.setTime(cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    return new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Comment: or just call cal.getTime() works too... It's far from pretty to do that in all case